# aws ec2 describe-instances not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

aws ec2 describe-instances

A client error (AuthFailure) occurred when calling the DescribeInstances operation:

```
AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials.
```

We unfortunately lost a box and we started to configure the ec2 instance from starting. We are group of four IAM users. I configured the box with my access key and security key and when I do `aws ec2 describe-instances`, it throws me this error. Should the instance have the access key from any other IAM users? Please help

Comment: did you set the access key in `.aws/credentials` and `.aws/config` for proper region?

Comment: @BMW 6, Yes I did sir

Comment: `aws --profile account1` and then try to put your account name on `account1`